# If the coordinate curves are geodesics, then $\partial_v E=\partial_u G=0$

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

We have a parametrized regular surface and its coordinate curves in some parametrization are geodesics. I started by noting that, if $g_u, g_v$ denote the tangent vectors to those curves, then $\nabla_{g_i} g_i=0\implies \Gamma_{ii}^k=0$, that is, them being geodesics means the non null Christoffel symbols only have mixed indices downstairs. But this got me nowhere seeing as (denoting the components of the 1st fundamental form by E,F,G) $\partial_v E=\partial_v(g_u\cdot g_u)=2\Gamma_{uv}^k g_k\cdot g_u$. The other derivative is analogous. How do I proceed to prove $\partial_v E=\partial_u G=0$?

Comment: First, don't you need to say that this is an orthogonal parametrization (i.e., $F=0$)? After that, it's just the equations for the Christoffel symbols and the equations for geodesics.

Comment: @TedShifrin is it orthogonal tho? I don't see how that is guaranteed. After all, if the surface is a plane for example I can parametrize it with the span of two linearly independent vectors, the coordinate curves of which are geodesics but are not orthogonal

Comment: If $F\ne 0$, then this result is false. Where did you get the exercise?

Comment: @TedShifrin it was provided by my DG professor. He most likely forgot that condition then. Thanks!